# Is there a faster way to increase/decrease a value besides using scripts in Google Sheets?

Tags: validation, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wgapukUmnkgW3qZLqZ8I-FgRI1kCBw4tYGNBJnxIv_Q/edit?usp=sharing

You can see I created up and down arrows that are used to increase/decrease the percentages in column `H`.
It's a little bit slow because it's run by a script. Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: Hi Reggie,
I'm curious where you got the formula to pull from Finviz.  I wrote pretty much that exact formula in a post on the GoogleCommunity Forums and it seems to have gotten a lot of traction for some odd reason!

Comment: I believe I found it in some google forum so it may be yours! If it is thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Data Validation` for the values in your `I` column

[image]

The formula for your named range could be

```
=ArrayFormula(SEQUENCE(11,1,14,2)/100)
```

As for the `Data Validation` you can use `List from a range` and use `my_percentages`.

Using the combination of `Named ranges` and `Data validation` will give you **instant results**.
*(Make a note that the named range can be anywhere. Even in a new tab.)*

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`SEQUENCE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244)